# How to access request.user from an admin ModelForm clean method?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

I'm doing some stuff on 'clean' on an admin ModelForm:

```
class MyAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean(self):
        # Some stuff happens...
        request.user.message_set.create(message="Some stuff happened")

class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyAdminForm
```

Other than the threadlocals hack - how do I access request.user to set a message? I can't pass it to the form constructor because doesn't get called from my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it on the form without passing the user into the form constructor.  Instead you can use the `ModelAdmin.save_model` function which is given the request object.

> The save_model method is given the
>   HttpRequest, a model instance, a
>   ModelForm instance and a boolean value
>   based on whether it is adding or
>   changing the object. Here you can do
>   any pre- or post-save operations.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model

Edit:
Since you want to put the logic/messages in the clean function you could do something like:

```
class MyAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    user_messages = []
    def clean(self):
        # Some stuff happens...
        user_messages.append("Some stuff happened")

class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyAdminForm
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        for message in form.user_messages:
            request.user.message_set.create(message=message)
```

Very late edit:

`user.message_set` is set to be deprecated in Django 1.4. You should instead use `ModelAdmin.message_user`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.message_user

Comment: Mmmmm. The message depends on some validation logic so make much more sense living in the ModelForm clean() method. If I move it to ModelAdmin save_model() I'm going to have to write some messy logic just for the sake of sending a message!

Comment: I moved user_messages into the form's init and added self. to the 'user_messages.append' line and that worked a treat! Thanks.

Comment: Adding user_messages as a class variable was problematic for me, as the messages accumulated. I solved it by adding user_messages in get_form of the ModelAdmin `def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
  form = super(ResortAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
  form.user_messages = []
  return form`
And yes, I needed to prepend `self` to the `user_messages.append()` call

Comment: Oh and remember to call `super(MyAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)`

Answer (score -1):

You would have to explicitly pass it there in constructor, which isn't a thing, that is usually done.

Are you sure you want to put that stuff into a form? What exactly you would like to do there? Isn't raising `ValidationError` enough?

Comment: As mentioned the Constructor isn't in my code - it's in contrib.admin.

The message I want send isn't an error. It's a notification when saving the form has affected another part of the system.

Comment: But this is strange - how can you be sure, that you should send the message before actually saving the the object from the form? There might happen many different things between clean and save.

Comment: Bearing in mind we are talking about the admin change view what is likely to happen between clean and save?

Comment: Other clean may raise a ValidationError.