# how to pre-fill an HiddenInput in admin ModelForm

Tags: django, forms, validation, django-admin

I'm sure that problems similar to the one I'm going to ask about were already discussed somewhere, but I always found very tricky solutions while I think there must be a very straightforward one (you can guess I'm a totally newbie).

I have a model (`Lecturer`) that is connected `OneToOne` to the `User` model:

```
class Lecturer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    ... other fiels follow ...
```

I'd like each user to create its own `Lecturer` object through the `admin` site.

My idea is to present to the user the `add_view` without the `user` field. Then I would something like `obj.user=request.user` when saving the model.

In other words, I don't want to give the user the possibility of selecting a different user among the registered for its own `Lecturer` object.

I modified the form by overriding the get_form method and by providing a custom form:

```
admin.py

class LecturerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if is_lecturer(request.user):
            kwargs['form'] = UserLecturerForm
        return super(LecturerAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)

class UserLecturerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Lecturer
        fields = ('__all__')
        widgets = {'user': forms.HiddenInput()}
```

I cannot just `exclude` the `user` field and give it a value at some other level (e.g. `save_model` or `clean` ...) because this raises an error at the template rendering level:

> Django Version:   1.7.7
>   Exception Type:     KeyError
>   Exception Value:    u"Key 'user' not found in 'LecturerForm'"
>   Exception Location:     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py in **getitem**, line 147
>   Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
>   Python Version:     2.7.9
>
> Error during template rendering
>   In template /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/includes/fieldset.html, error at line 7
>   [...]
>   7   `<div class="form-row{% if line.fields|length_is:'1' and line.errors %} errors{% endif %}{% if not line.has_visible_field %} hidden{% endif %}{% for field in line %}{% if field.field.name %} field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}">`

I tried making the `user` field `hidden` in the form. But then the problem came of how to give it the correct `request.user` value, given that the form doesn't know anything about the `request`. If I don't fill it with a valid value, the form will not validate (and I cannot use solutions involving the `save_model` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252128/how-to-access-request-user-from-an-admin-modelform-clean-method))

I found solutions that involve changing the view, but I wouldn't do it in the admin context.

An alternative would be to change the validation behavior, but still validation is a method of the form and the form doesn't know `request`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There's no reason why excluding it from the form would give "an error" in the template. That is the correct thing to do: you should show the error you're getting.

Comment: I just excluded 'user' from UserLecturerForm and I got what I reported in the quoted block in the edited version of my post. I don't understand (among many others) why the error report mentions 'LecturerForm' instead of 'UserLecturerForm' which is the form passed to the add_view if user is not superuser.

Comment: @Daniel, given your strong opinion, I convinced myself I did the right thing when I tried first to exclude 'user'. I rebuilt a toy project to test it and it works. There must be something else bad in my code. I'll catch it. Thank you.